# On the Irreducibility of $x^2+x+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I came across with the following problem.

> The following statements are equivalent for a prime $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}$:
>
> (1) $x^2+x+1$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.
>
> (2)  $p\equiv 2\pmod 3$

I was able to prove $(2)\Rightarrow(1)$. I got stuck on proving  $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$. Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could say "quadratic reciprocity"...

But I won't. (1) implies (2) iff $x^2+x+1$ is reducible modulo
$p$ for $p=3$ or $p\equiv1\pmod 3$. For $p=3$, $x^2+x+1\equiv(x-1)^2\pmod 3$. Otherwise, $p=3k+1$, and let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$
and $a=g^k$. Then $a^3\equiv1\pmod p$ but $a\not\equiv1\pmod p$. Then
$0\equiv(a-1)(a^2+a+1)\pmod p$, so that $a^2+a+1\equiv0\pmod p$.
Thus $x-a$ is a factor of $x^2+x+1$ over $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$.

Comment: May I know why $a\not\equiv 1\pmod p$?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan As I said, $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.

Comment: I got it already. More power.